# Azure data factory - Continuous deployment using VSTS

Tags: deployment, azure-data-factory

I need to know how can i build continuous deployment for Azure Data factory using VSTS. I know there is an Azure data factory deployment available in VSTS release. But I'm looking for other options using Powershell for deployment.

If anyone has already done anything specific to this provide the links.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, since you are specifically asking for Powershell. I would really look into using ARM templates for ADF deployments, highly recommended

Comment: I have done automation of ADF using PowerShell, I can deploy All parts of ADF using PowerShell as well as MS defined tasks in Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](https://blog.abatishchev.ru/2017/03/28/352) should get you started. I'm using a comparable method for deployment. Before deploying the JSON files using a PowerShell command, I edit them to insert environment specific values into the Data Factory definitions. You can pass these values as parameters from the TFS deployment-pipeline.

Comment: i need to do continuous deployment of Azure data factory using vsts through powershell...if  you can provide any links or ways to do it would be great

Comment: The blog in your link will deploy ADF using Powershell..but if i need to configure the same to run using VSTS..how do i need to proceed..

Comment: I have a deployment project in my solution. This project contains ARM-templates and PowerShell scripts that are used during deployment. In this project I have a PowerShell file handles the DF deployment. 

During the build, the deployment project files are passed as artifacts which can be used in the release pipline. In the release I use an Azure Powershell task to run the DF deployment script.

Comment: In the azure powershell script during deployment do we need to include the login-azurermaccount for logging in. And if yes how do i parameterize it.